# styled-theming multiple values inside theme

Tags: styled-components

I'm currently discovered styled components and styled-theming  and I'm curios, can I specify multiple values inside theme . I'll explain...

So in examples we have this code:

```
const boxBg = theme('mode', {
  light: '#fff',
  dark: '#000'
})

const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: ${boxBg};
`;
```

But can I do like this ?

```
const boxStyles = theme('mode', {
  light: {
    color: #000,
    bg: #fff
  }
  //...
})

const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: ${boxStyles.bg};
  color: ${boxStyles.color};
`;
```

One solution, which I've found, is:

```
const Color = theme('mode', {
  //- styles for color })
const Bg = theme('mode', {
  //- styles for bg })

const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: ${Bg};
  color: ${Color };
`;
```

But it's a bit weird and just imagine you have 4-5 different 'modes' and 4-5 different values to style.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing (and no, it's not what Simons0n suggested). What we want is a collection of styles that form a theme, not a single-attribute theme like so many of the examples.

Fortunately, I found this article: https://jsramblings.com/2017/11/05/theming-with-styled-components.html, and the companion implementation and code sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/q0wxr0l4.

There, the author (Corina Udrescu) demonstrates exactly what we want--styles grouped to form themes, as in:

```
const dayTheme = {
  skyColor: '#37d8e6',
  celestialObjectColor: '#ffdd00',
  celestialObjectBorderColor: '#f1c40f'
};

const nightTheme = {
  skyColor: '#2c3e50',
  celestialObjectColor: '#bdc3c7',
  celestialObjectBorderColor: '#eaeff2'
}
```

and then referenced by name, as in

```
const Sky = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.skyColor}
`
```

The main styled-components documentation also shows this at https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming, where the themes are

```
// Define our `fg` and `bg` on the theme
const theme = {
  fg: 'palevioletred',
  bg: 'white'
};

// This theme swaps `fg` and `bg`
const invertTheme = ({ fg, bg }) => ({
  fg: bg,
  bg: fg
});
```

but unfortunately they don't have a good example of switching themes (just applying selectively). As Corina shows, using state to control the them is the key to dynamic theme switching:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={this.state.theme}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this, that you are searching?

```
const theme = {
    mainColor: 'green',
    mainBgColor: 'red'
};

const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.mainColor};
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.mainBgColor};
`;
```

What you can not do is, to put multiple themes on one component. That also would not make alot of sense, as the Themeproviders should be used for styling different areas of your application. Like, there should not be a theme for bgcolors and one theme for font colors. It should be a theme for the header and for the footer, for example, where bgcolor and font color are different.

Here is some additional information about theming: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird to think about multiples "modes".

The first alternative is to do something like:

```
const boxStyles = theme('mode', {
  light: css`
    background: ${white};
    color: ${black};
  `,
  dark: css`
    background: ${black};
    color: ${white};
  `,
});

const Box = styled.div`
  ${boxStyles}
`;
```

> I got this example from [style-theming official repo](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-theming)

The second alternative is to do:

```
theme('mode', {
  light: '#fff',
  dark: '#000',
});

theme('font', {
  sansSerif: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  serif: 'Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif',
  monoSpaced: 'Consolas, monaco, monospace',
});
```

> I got the example from [styled-theming official repo](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-theming)

If you notice the second alternative, the author uses multiples 'names' to differ from each property he wants to theme...

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the `boxStyles` constant an object and call theme multiple times inside of it. As of now, I don't think it's an option in styled-components to do this without either defining a persisting set of properties like in Andrew's answer or call theme multiple times as shown below:

```
const buttonColors = {
    backgroundColor: theme("mode", {
        light: "white",
        dark: "black",
    }),
    color: theme("mode", {
        light: "black",
        dark: "white",
    }),
};
```

Note that this allows you to style it both ways.

First way:

You can pass it directly into styled as follows:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    ${buttonColors}`
`
```

Second way:

Or like in your question originally as:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background-color:${buttonColors.backgroundColor};
    color:${buttonColors.color};
`;
```

**NOTE** This also allows you to have a defined theme and overwrite(overwrite will work as long as you pass your custom properties **after** you import the whole component(as shown in the first way)

Comment: you can also have multiple properties in buttonColors and make your own theme in a different file and import it to keep it as neat as you'd want